# How to fish NM cable up, over, and back down

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to fish a cable up from an outlet/switch box, over a door, and back down to a box outside. What is the best method to fish the cable?

Comment: Do you have access below (unfinished basement, crawlspace)? Do you have access above (attic)?

Comment: @Tester101 hints at the better alternative - usually you'll want to make the horizontal run in the attic or the basement, if you have access above or below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accept the need to do drywall repair.**

---

Knock some access holes. Unless you are going into an accessible (attic, say) space to go "over a door" you need to drill holes in studs - and if there happen to be holes there now, you still are not going to be able to fish through them without some access holes, IMPE.

Comment: There is an existing wire already there. Will that help anything? Very hesitant to cut walls as it is paneling from the 80's.

Comment: Unless you have access to some military-spec camera-guided robot technology, this is your answer.

Comment: Paneling can actually be a boon - if you carefully remove a few sheets, the quality of drywall repair needed (assuming it even is over drywall) goes way, way down.

Comment: Paneling is often installed with very small trim nails. Find (or make) a nail set with the right size tip and drive the nails through the paneling to remove it.

Comment: Remember paneling is sometimes glued on ... trying to remove it could go way wrong.